# Rails: acts_as_taggable_on, getting errors when attempting to find articles by tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been following along with a RailsCasts episode, and am trying to make articles taggable. Then I want to make tags clickable on articles show.html page, so that users can find other related articles. I am using Rails 4. However, I have been getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show

Couldn't find Article without an ID

Extracted source (around line #43):

def show 
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

I then tried to make the following changes, which I observed after looking at the RailsCast code:

**articles_controller.rb**

```
[...]
    def show  
        if params[:tag]
          @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        else
          @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        end
    end
```

Which gave me the error upon clicking a tag on a working show page:

**http://localhost:x000/tags/pizza**

```
NoMethodError in Articles#show
undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass

<div id="article-title">
  <h1>
   <p>
    <%= @article.title %></span>
   </p>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Which seems odd to me, since the title method works just fine otherwise. Everything else works on the site, the tags save and can be edited in the articles edit page, but finding all articles with a specific tag isn't working.

===
Relevant code areas:

**_form.html**

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :keyword_Tags %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %> <span class="gray-text"><em>Separated by commas; single tag has no spaces, only-dashes </em></span>
  </p>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Network::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :libraries

  get "libraries/show"
  devise_for :authors, :controllers => {:registrations => "authors/registrations"}

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#show', as: :tag 

  devise_scope :author do
    get 'signup', to: 'devise/registrations#new' 
    get 'signin', to: 'devise/sessions#new' 
    # get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
  end

  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  get "landing_page/index"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'landing_page#index'
  get '/:id', to: 'libraries#show'
end
```

**article.rb**

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :author 
    acts_as_taggable
    acts_as_taggable_on :tag_list

    validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :text, presence: true,
                                 length: { minimum: 2 }
    validates :article_start, presence: true,
                                        length: {minimum: 10}

end
```

**[num]_create_articles.rb**

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.time :era
      t.string :chapter
      t.date :article_start
      t.text :text
      t.string :tag_list

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_author!, only: [:create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#added destroy to above, not in Treebook

def index
    @articles = Article.all 
end

def new # diff between new and create?
    @article = Article.new
end

def create 
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    #respond_to do|format|

    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article 
    else
        render 'new'

    end
end
#end #for respond_to; noticed in "What is a join table"

def show #show, being an action
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

end


def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
end



private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :author_id, :article_start, :era, :chapter, :address, :tag_list)
    end
```

end

**Request**

```
Parameters:

{"tag"=>"open"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `ArticlesController` actions `show` and `index` as below:

```
   def show  
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

   def index  
     if params[:tag]
       @articles = Article.tagged_with(params[:tag])
     else
       @articles = Article.all
     end
   end
```

Also, update the `routes.rb` :

**Replace**

```
 get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#show', as: :tag
```

**With**

```
 get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#index', as: :tag ## It should go to index action not show
```

Comment: Hi Kirti, I'm still getting `undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass`. The application didn't say one way or another what it thought about the fix. Any other suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: I updated the post. My options were full, framework and application. Let me know if need another.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How are you calling show action? Share the relevant code OR see my updated answer for example how would I call it through my application.

Comment: Hi Kirti, I am a novice Rails user. Did you mean, when you say call, the `<%= raw @article.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ')%>` in my show.html? I don't know what file you are referring to, other than controller. I will update def show in meantime.

Comment: I am referring to the view which has a link to the show page of article, clicking on which you get this error.

Comment: Maybe that's my problem :) I don't know if I have that anywhere. I have the new.html.erb, which holds _form.html.erb, then that makes the show.html.erb. The show.html.erb page holds the list.map code I mentioned. How can I confirm I have or do not have what you are referring to? And when I update def show, I get the couldn't find article without ID error I had in beginning.

Comment: Remove the stacktrace from the question as it is getting too lengthy. Add the controller code to the question.

Comment: I updated with articles controller. SO was taking very long to update.

Comment: Last hope is if you could share the server log (from terminal where rails server is running) when you get this error.

Comment: Hi Kirti! I appreciate your help, even we can't find the solution today. I made a google docs post of the server output, so the main post won't take too much space. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1atpar6VIIFx2qlptY3fd3sWYw4tV1pLtBLVMjKrfpHQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I found the issue. I have updated my answer, follow it exactly.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. The index does make more sense, since it is scoping.

Comment: May I ask how you figured it out, I didn't understand it from the server log. I'd like to get better at solving Rails issues too.

Comment: As per the server log, you were requesting for `tags/pear`which was going to show action obviously without an `id`. `tags/pear` should actually list all the articles which are tagged with `pear`. So you had mapped the request to wrong action. It should have been mapped to `index` action.